# Symmetry in Biology

Tags: literature, symmetry

It seems a curious fact to me that all organisms I can think of exhibit some definite symmetry on a large scale (much larger than molecules), and in particular mirror symmetry. Since it is so wide spread, I imagine there is some deep reason for it. One thing that comes to mind, is that it might take less genome to encode. Are there any such reasons?

Comment: Welcome to SE.biology! It's expected that you show some evidence that you've tried to research the question before posting here. Please take a read of the [help centre section on how to ask a good question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider editing your post. There is a [whole wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_in_biology) dedicated to the topic which should be read before posting questions. Thanks.

Comment: please provide with some evidence that back you research